# Parse HTTP response in C#

Tags: c#, query-string, httpresponse

I want to split HttpResponse using C#.

I got a response like this:

```
&url=http:\\\example.com&type=abcd&quality=best
```

I want to store url and type in a string
I don't know how to do this. I can do this in Java like this:

```
String response = GetURL("http://example2.com?info_id=" + id);
String Info = DecodeUrlFormEncoded(response);
String url = Info.get("url");
String type = Info.get("type");
```

I have done my Coding Like this

```
        string str = "http://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?video_id=tmeOjFno6Do";
        Stream objStream;
        StreamReader objSR;
        System.Text.Encoding encode = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8");
        HttpWebRequest wrquest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(str);
        HttpWebResponse getresponse = null;
        getresponse = (HttpWebResponse)wrquest.GetResponse();

        objStream = getresponse.GetResponseStream();
        objSR = new StreamReader(objStream, encode, true);
        string strResponse = objSR.ReadToEnd();
```

### Got this response

midroll_freqcap=420.0&iurlmaxres=http%3A%2F%2Fi.ytimg.com%2Fvi%2FSZrCWa38KHk%2Fmaxresdefault.jpg&status=ok&shortform=True&use_cipher_signature=False&eventid=kZZIVN_XF4_FugT2nYDIBw&watermark=%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fs.ytimg.com%2Fyts%2Fimg%2Fwatermark%2Fyoutube_watermark-vflHX6b6E.png%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fs.ytimg.com%2Fyts%2Fimg%2Fwatermark%2Fyoutube_hd_watermark-vflAzLcD6.png&allow_embed=1&timestamp=1414043281&avg_rating=4.74417009602&title=Kaththi+-+Selfie+Pulla+Official+Song+Promo+%7C+Vijay%2C+Samantha+Ruth+Prabhu+%7C+A.R.+Murugadoss%2C+Anirudh&pltype=content&csi_page_type=embed&allow_ratings=1&no_get_video_log=1&ldpj=-4&cut_ad_for_ypc=False&cos=Windows&enablecsi=1&adaptive_fmts=init%3D0-712%26type%3Dvideo%252Fmp4%253B%2Bcodecs%253D%2522avc1.640028%2522%26size%3D1920x1080%26url%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fr12---sn-cvh7zn7z.googlevideo.com%252Fvideoplayback%253Fsource%253Dyoutube%2526sparams%253Dclen%25252Cdur%25252Cgir%25252Cid%25252Cinitcwndbps%25252Cip%25252Cipbits%25252Citag%25252Clmt%25252Cmm%25252Cms%25252Cmv%25252Csource%25252Cupn%25252Cexpire%2526mv%253Dm%2526initcwndbps%253D630000%2526ms%253Dau%2526sver%253D3%2526dur%253D41.791%2526gir%253Dyes%2526key%253Dyt5%2526signature%253DC18B50FC879009AAF2B47341FD67BC07DDEBDD09.3B4E800C557EE96ECA340E2D35FF7CCE4BD8EE52%2526mm%253D31%2526upn%253DvaHONPfT0Mo%2526itag%253D137%2526ipbits%253D0%2526mt%253D1414043211%2526clen%253D21330256%2526id%253Do-AGo93ElNwiIuEXZTNdJN54VvKBf_28RexQxNuPDZKW-q%2526expire%253D1414064881%2526fexp%253D910100%25252C916942%25252C924619%25252C927622%25252C930666%25252C930672%25252C931983%25252C932404%25252C935000%25252C935679%25252C942484%25252C945073%25252C947209%25252C947225%25252C948703%25252C952302%2526ip%253D115.118.224.92%2526lmt%253D1413564052869920%26clen%3D21330256%26index%3D713-852%26lmt%3D1413564052869920%26fps%3D24%26itag%3D137%26bitrate%3D4163747%2Cinit%3D0-234%26type%3Dvideo%252Fwebm%253B%2Bcodecs%253D%2522vp9%2522%26size%3D1920x1080%26url%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fr12---sn-cvh7zn7z.googlevideo.com%252Fvideoplayback%253Fsource%253Dyoutube%2526sparams%253Dclen%25252Cdur%25252Cgir%25252Cid%25252Cinitcwndbps%25252Cip%25252Cipbits%25252Citag%25252Clmt%25252Cmm%25252Cms%25252Cmv%25252Csource%25252Cupn%25252Cexpire%2526mv%253Dm%2526initcwndbps%253D630000%2526ms%253Dau%2526sver%253D3%2526dur%253D41.750%2526gir%253Dyes%2526key%253Dyt5%2526signature%253D61219B6D9D0383E481B47437CB238F1C537E716F.66D4A2AA732E5674B4A267F108F9252895F02C87%2526mm%253D31%2526upn%253DvaHONPfT0Mo%2526itag%253D248%2526ipbits%253D0%2526mt%253D1414043211%2526clen%253D14635348%2526id%253Do-AGo93ElNwiIuEXZTNdJN54VvKBf_28RexQxNuPDZKW-q%2526expire%253D1414064881%2526fexp%253D910100%25252C916942%25252C924619%25252C927622%25252C930666%25252C930672%25252C931983%25252C932404%25252C935000%25252C935679%25252C942484%25252C945073%25252C947209%25252C947225%25252C948703%25252C952302%2526ip%253D115.118.224.92%2526lmt%253D1413613467329399%26clen%3D14635348%26index%3D235-382%26lmt%3D1413613467329399%26fps%3D24%26itag%3D248%26bitrate%3D3079905%2Cinit%3D0-710%26type%3Dvideo%252Fmp4%253B%2Bcodecs%253D%2522avc1.4d401f%2522%26size%3D1280x720%26url%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fr12---sn-cvh7zn7z.googlevideo.com%252Fvideoplayback%253Fsource%253Dyoutube%2526sparams%253Dclen%25252Cdur%25252Cgir%25252Cid%25252Cinitcwndbps%25252Cip%25252Cipbits%25252Citag%25252Clmt%25252Cmm%25252Cms%25252Cmv%25252Csource%25252Cupn%25252Cexpire%2526mv%253Dm%2526initcwndbps%253D630000%2526ms%253Dau%2526sver%253D3%2526dur%253D41.791%2526gir%253Dyes%2526key%253Dyt5%2526signature%253DF09D599CCD80C26564DA9AF5D4B16A89634D9B05.18590B5080AD738963778C6A4EC7EA032A7A0A04%2526mm%253D31%2526upn%253DvaHONPfT0Mo%2526itag%253D136%2526ipbits%253D0%2526mt%253D1414043211%2526clen%253D11374854%2526id%253Do-AGo93ElNwiIuEXZTNdJN54VvKBf_28RexQxNuPDZKW-q%2526expire%253D1414064881%2526fexp%253D910100%25252C916942%25252C924619%25252C927622%25252C930666%25252C930672%25252C931983%25252C932404%25252C935000%25252C935679%25252C942484%25252C945073%25252C947209%25252C947225%25252C948703%25252C952302%2526ip%253D115.118.224.92%2526lmt%253D1413564045989922%26clen%3D11374854%26index%3D711-850%26lmt%3D1413564045989922%26fps%3D24%26itag%3D136%26bitrate%3D2222267%2Cinit%3D0-234%26type%3Dvideo%252Fwebm%253B%2Bcodecs%253D%2522vp9%2522%26size%3D1280x720%26url%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fr12---sn-cvh7zn7z.googlevideo.com%252Fvideoplayback%253Fsource%253Dyoutube%2526sparams%253Dclen%25252Cdur%25252Cgir%25252Cid%25252Cinitcwndbps%25252Cip%25252Cipbits%25252Citag%25252Clmt%25252Cmm%25252Cms%25252Cmv%25252Csource%25252Cupn%25252Cexpire%2526mv%253Dm%2526initcwndbps%253D630000%2526ms%253Dau%2526sver%253D3%2526dur%253D41.750%2526gir%253Dyes%2526key%253Dyt5%2526signature%253D26495B62B77D1FCFD82E9293ED7B2B2EA459DE88.4C23E5B44D22E9C8A7EC0C40EDF0D37AB9CCC242%2526mm%253D31%2526upn%253DvaHONPfT0Mo%2526itag%253D247%2526ipbits%253D0%2526mt%253D1414043211%2526clen%253D8822806%2526id%253Do-AGo93ElNwiIuEXZTNdJN54VvKBf_28RexQxNuPDZKW-q%2526expire%253D1414064881%2526fexp%253D910100%25252C916942%25252C924619%25252C927622%25252C930666%25252C930672%25252C931983%25252C932404%25252C935000%25252C935679%25252C942484%25252C945073%25252C947209%25252C947225%25252C948703%25252C952302%2526ip%253D115.118.224.92%2526lmt%253D1413610420552425%26clen%3D8822806%26index%3D235-382%26lmt%3D1413610420552425%26fps%3D24%26itag%3D247%26bitrate%3D1835088%2Cinit%3D0-709%26type%3Dvideo%252Fmp4%253B%2Bcodecs%253D%2522avc1.4d401e%2522%26size%3D854x480%26url%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fr12---sn-cvh7zn7z.googlevideo.com%252Fvideoplayback%253Fsource%253Dyoutube%2526sparams%253Dclen%25252Cdur%25252Cgir%25252Cid%25252Cinitcwndbps%25252Cip%25252Cipbits%25252Citag%25252Clmt%25252Cmm%25252Cms%25252Cmv%25252Csource%25252Cupn%25252Cexpire%2526mv%253Dm%2526initcwndbps%253D630000%2526ms%253Dau%2526sver%253D3%2526dur%253D41.791%2526gir%253Dyes%2526key%253Dyt5%2526signature%253DA99A802C5C8EE1E827493194670D964E98E0BC55.3A51B45CBD947EE2D15937BA22E78283E8F84F2D%2526mm%253D31%2526upn%253DvaHONPfT0Mo%2526itag%253D135%2526ipbits%253D0%2526mt%253D1414043211%2526clen%253D5665543%2526id%253Do-AGo93ElNwiIuEXZTNdJN54VvKBf_28RexQxNuPDZKW-q%2526expire%253D1414064881%2526fexp%253D910100%25252C916942%25252C924619%25252C927622%25252C930666%25252C930672%25252C931983%25252C932404%25252C935000%25252C935679%25252C942484%25252C945073%25252C947209%25252C947225%25252C948703%25252C952302%2526ip%253D115.118.224.92%2526lmt%253D1413564039127537%26clen%3D5665543%26index%3D710-849%26lmt%3D1413564039127537%26fps%3D24%26itag%3D135%26bitrate%3D1112278%2Cinit%3D0-234%26type%3Dvideo%252Fwebm%253B%2Bcodecs%253D%2522vp9%2522%26size%3D854x480%26url%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fr12---sn-cvh7zn7z.googlevideo.com%252Fvideoplayback%253Fsource%253Dyoutube%2526sparams%253Dclen%25252Cdur%25252Cgir%25252Cid%25252Cinitcwndbps%25252Cip%25252Cipbits%25252Citag%25252Clmt%25252Cmm%25252Cms%25252Cmv%25252Csource%25252Cupn%25252Cexpire%2526mv%253Dm%2526initcwndbps%253D630000%2526ms%253Dau%2526sver%253D3%2526dur%253D41.750%2526gir%253Dyes%2526key%253Dyt5%2526signature%253D4E88104E4939E5A60C7C6648F252196C665D8712.A1AEDC139751B068D3FCA2A9B95F3518FF62C021%2526mm%253D31%2526upn%253DvaHONPfT0Mo%2526itag%253D244%2526ipbits%253D0%2526mt%253D1414043211%2526clen%253D4581030%2526id%253Do-AGo93ElNwiIuEXZTNdJN54VvKBf_28RexQxNuPDZKW-q%2526expire%253D1414064881%2526fexp%253D910100%25252C916942%25252C924619%25252C927622%25252C930666%25252C930672%25252C931983%25252C932404%25252C935000%25252C935679%25252C942484%25252C945073%25252C947209%25252C947225%25252C948703%25252C952302%2526ip%253D115.118.224.92%2526lmt%253D1413610513879325%26clen%3D4581030%26index%3D235-382%26lmt%3D1413610513879325%26fps%3D24%26itag%3D244%26bitrate%3D949971%2Cinit%3D0-709%26type%3Dvideo%252Fmp4%253B%2Bcodecs%253D%2522avc1.4d401e%2522%26size%3D640x360%26url%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fr12---sn-cvh7zn7z.googlevideo.com%252Fvideoplayback%253Fsource%253Dyoutube%2526sparams%253Dclen%25252Cdur%25252Cgir%25252Cid%25252Cinitcwndbps%25252Cip%25252Cipbits%25252Citag%25252Clmt%25252Cmm%25252Cms%25252Cmv%25252Csource%25252Cupn%25252Cexpire%2526mv%253Dm%2526initcwndbps%253D630000%2526ms%253Dau%2526sver%253D3%2526dur%253D41.791%2526gir%253Dyes%2526key%253Dyt5%2526signature%253DF6DA5EFFE930BAF7A3E982519DBA83F3478E146A.087ACD7CAF945DCE2AE576A06FAD6BF95BFFD066%2526mm%253D31%2526upn%253DvaHONPfT0Mo%2526itag%253D134%2526ipbits%253D0%2526mt%253D1414043211%2526clen%253D3082898%2526id%253Do-AGo93ElNwiIuEXZTNdJN54VvKBf_28RexQxNuPDZKW-q%2526expire%253D1414064881%2526fexp%253D910100%25252C916942%25252C924619%25252C927622%25252C930666%25252C930672%25252C931983%25252C932404%25252C935000%25252C935679%25252C942484%25252C945073%25252C947209%25252C947225%25252C948703%25252C952302%2526ip%253D115.118.224.92%2526lmt%253D1413564034033943%26clen%3D3082898%26index%3D710-849%26lmt%3D1413564034033943%26fps%3D24%26itag%3D134%26bitrate%3D607812%2Cinit%3D0-234%26type%3Dvideo%252Fwebm%253B%2Bcodecs%253D%2522vp9%2522%26size%3D640x360%26url%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fr12---sn-cvh7zn7z.googlevideo.com%252Fvideoplayback%253Fsource%253Dyoutube%2526sparams%253Dclen%25252Cdur%25252Cgir%25252Cid%25252Cinitcwndbps%25252Cip%25252Cipbits%25252Citag%25252Clmt%25252Cmm%25252Cms%25252Cmv%25252Csource%25252Cupn%25252Cexpire%2526mv%253Dm%2526initcwndbps%253D630000%2526ms%253Dau%2526sver%253D3%2526dur%253D41.750%2526gir%253Dyes%2526key%253Dyt5%2526signature%253D07921146F8BE361E175B29CFA81927D375048471.84CC47CE55D2AF6D5E83C755B74073482D709A15%2526mm%253D31%2526upn%253DvaHONPfT0Mo%2526itag%253D243%2526ipbits%253D0%2526mt%253D1414043211%2526clen%253D2153845%2526id%253Do-AGo93ElNwiIuEXZTNdJN54VvKBf_28RexQxNuPDZKW-q%2526expire%253D1414064881%2526fexp%253D910100%25252C916942%25252C924619%25252C927622%25252C930666%25252C930672%25252C931983%25252C932404%25252C935000%25252C935679%25252C942484%25252C945073%25252C947209%25252C947225%25252C948703%25252C952302%2526ip%253D115.118.224.92%2526lmt%253D1413610339847414%26clen%3D2153845%26index%3D235-382%26lmt%3D1413610339847414%26fps%3D24%26itag%3D243%26bitrate%3D447569%2Cinit%3D0-674%26type%3Dvideo%252Fmp4%253B%2Bcodecs%253D%2522avc1.4d4015%2522%26size%3D426x240%26url%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fr12---sn-cvh7zn7z.googlevideo.com%252Fvideoplayback%253Fsource%253Dyoutube%2526sparams%253Dclen%25252Cdur%25252Cgir%25252Cid%25252Cinitcwndbps%25252Cip%25252Cipbits%25252Citag%25252Clmt%25252Cmm%25252Cms%25252Cmv%25252Csource%25252Cupn%25252Cexpire%2526mv%253Dm%2526initcwndbps%253D630000%2526ms%253Dau%2526sver%253D3%2526dur%253D41.791%2526gir%253Dyes%2526key%253Dyt5%2526signature%253D8C4308FC37D8A46A93A8A3DB5E121DFD427663A3.D056D70023A91664D868EC55123919B82E895979%2526mm%253D31%2526upn%253DvaHONPfT0Mo%2526itag%253D133%2526ipbits%253D0%2526mt%253D1414043211%2526clen%253D1277857%2526id%253Do-AGo93ElNwiIuEXZTNdJN54VvKBf_28RexQxNuPDZKW-q%2526expire%253D1414064881%2526fexp%253D910100%25252C916942%25252C924619%25252C927622%25252C930666%25252C930672%25252C931983%25252C932404%25252C935000%25252C935679%25252C942484%25252C945073%25252C947209%25252C947225%25252C948703%25252C952302%2526ip%253D115.118.224.92%2526lmt%253D1413564031438445%26clen%3D1277857%26index%3D675-814%26lmt%3D1413564031438445%26fps%3D24%26itag%3D133%26bitrate%3D246166%2Cinit%3D0-233%26type%3Dvideo%252Fwebm%253B%2Bcodecs%253D%2522vp9%2522%26size%3D426x240%26url%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fr12---sn-cvh7zn7z.googlevideo.com%252Fvideoplayback%253Fsource%253Dyoutube%2526sparams%253Dclen%25252Cdur%25252Cgir%25252Cid%25252Cinitcwndbps%25252Cip%25252Cipbits%25252Citag%25252Clmt%25252Cmm%25252Cms%25252Cmv%25252Csource%25252Cupn%25252Cexpire%2526mv%253Dm%2526initcwndbps%253D630000%2526ms%253Dau%2526sver%253D3%2526dur%253D41.750%2526gir%253Dyes%2526key%253Dyt5%2526signature%253D4077673EBB634D6535DE4DAE170889CD447D99A1.6E0A58E73A94EF0DD355A9F25BC62788177C65FD%2526mm%253D31%2526upn%253DvaHONPfT0Mo%2526itag%253D242%2526ipbits%253D0%2526mt%253D1414043211%2526clen%253D1162313%2526id%253Do-AGo93ElNwiIuEXZTNdJN54VvKBf_28RexQxNuPDZKW-q%2526expire%253D1414064881%2526fexp%253D910100%25252C916942%25252C924619%25252C927622%25252C930666%25252C930672%25252C931983%25252C932404%25252C935000%25252C935679%25252C942484%25252C945073%25252C947209%25252C947225%25252C948703%25252C952302%2526ip%253D115.118.224.92%2526lmt%253D1413610327663052%26clen%3D1162313%26index%3D234-381%26lmt%3D1413610327663052%26fps%3D24%26itag%3D242%26bitrate%3D245020%2Cinit%3D0-671%26type%3Dvideo%252Fmp4%253B%2Bcodecs%253D%2522avc1.42c00c%2522%26size%3D256x144%26url%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fr12---sn-cvh7zn7z.googlevideo.com%252Fvideoplayback%253Fsource%253Dyoutube%2526sparams%253Dclen%25252Cdur%25252Cgir%25252Cid%25252Cinitcwndbps%25252Cip%25252Cipbits%25252Citag%25252Clmt%25252Cmm%25252Cms%25252Cmv%25252Csource%25252Cupn%25252Cexpire%2526mv%253Dm%2526initcwndbps%253D630000%2526ms%253Dau%2526sver%253D3%2526dur%253D41.833%2526gir%253Dyes%2526key%253Dyt5%2526signature%253D40B8F392BFE6212D9F52EFA5E8B603E763953A9A.58671CBD482FEBB4DDA88219BC99C6FAC66B9FB7%2526mm%253D31%2526upn%253DvaHONPfT0Mo%2526itag%253D160%2526ipbits%253D0%2526mt%253D1414043211%2526clen%253D569681%2526id%253Do-AGo93ElNwiIuEXZTNdJN54VvKBf_28RexQxNuPDZKW-q%2526expire%253D1414064881%2526fexp%253D910100%25252C916942%25252C924619%25252C927622%25252C930666%25252C930672%25252C931983%25252C932404%25252C935000%25252C935679%25252C942484%25252C945073%25252C947209%25252C947225%25252C948703%25252C952302%2526ip%253D115.118.224.92%2526lmt%253D1413564032075018%26clen%3D569681%26index%3D672-811%26lmt%3D1413564032075018%26fps%3D12%26itag%3D160%26bitrate%3D110110%2Cinit%3D0-591%26type%3Daudio%252Fmp4%253B%2Bcodecs%253D%2522mp4a.40.2%2522%26url%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fr12---sn-cvh7zn7z.googlevideo.com%252Fvideoplayback%253Fsource%253Dyoutube%2526sparams%253Dclen%25252Cdur%25252Cgir%25252Cid%25252Cinitcwndbps%25252Cip%25252Cipbits%25252Citag%25252Clmt%25252Cmm%25252Cms%25252Cmv%25252Csource%25252Cupn%25252Cexpire%2526mv%253Dm%2526initcwndbps%253D630000%2526ms%253Dau%2526sver%253D3%2526dur%253D41.842%2526gir%253Dyes%2526key%253Dyt5%2526signature%253D56856FA3E3989E30F28877842A1E84827BD2BE36.D68A979B3282C4F76D0BB177B000B622D3E86594%2526mm%253D31%2526upn%253DvaHONPfT0Mo%2526itag%253D140%2526ipbits%253D0%2526mt%253D1414043211%2526clen%253D672443%2526id%253Do-AGo93ElNwiIuEXZTNdJN54VvKBf_28RexQxNuPDZKW-q%2526expire%253D1414064881%2526fexp%253D910100%25252C916942%25252C924619%25252C927622%25252C930666%25252C930672%25252C931983%25252C932404%25252C935000%25252C935679%25252C942484%25252C945073%25252C947209%25252C947225%25252C948703%25252C952302%2526ip%253D115.118.224.92%2526lmt%253D1413564031383854%26clen%3D672443%26index%3D592-683%26lmt%3D1413564031383854%26itag%3D140%26bitrate%3D129372%2Cinit%3D0-4451%26type%3Daudio%252Fwebm%253B%2Bcodecs%253D%2522vorbis%2522%26url%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fr12---sn-cvh7zn7z.googlevideo.com%252Fvideoplayback%253Fsource%253Dyoutube%2526sparams%253Dclen%25252Cdur%25252Cgir%25252Cid%25252Cinitcwndbps%25252Cip%25252Cipbits%25252Citag%25252Clmt%25252Cmm%25252Cms%25252Cmv%25252Csource%25252Cupn%25252Cexpire%2526mv%253Dm%2526initcwndbps%253D630000%2526ms%253Dau%2526sver%253D3%2526dur%253D41.789%2526gir%253Dyes%2526key%253Dyt5%2526signature%253D32556B688A61B362C4F7DACCC645071734F64303.3A65E255C1F23AFB64C4AE13560AEDA2FEDAFB8A%2526mm%253D31%2526upn%253DvaHONPfT0Mo%2526itag%253D171%2526ipbits%253D0%2526mt%253D1414043211%2526clen%253D681955%2526id%253Do-AGo93ElNwiIuEXZTNdJN54VvKBf_28RexQxNuPDZKW-q%2526expire%253D1414064881%2526fexp%253D910100%25252C916942%25252C924619%25252C927622%25252C930666%25252C930672%25252C931983%25252C932404%25252C935000%25252C935679%25252C942484%25252C945073%25252C947209%25252C947225%25252C948703%25252C952302%2526ip%253D115.118.224.92%2526lmt%253D1413610325232966%26clen%3D681955%26index%3D4452-4534%26lmt%3D1413610325232966%26itag%3D171%26bitrate%3D145498&c=WEB&ad_flags=0&idpj=-2&muted=0&ad_logging_flag=1&iv_invideo_url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fannotations_invideo%3Fcap_hist%3D1%26cta%3D2%26video_id%3DSZrCWa38KHk&iv_load_policy=1&cosver=6.1&adsense_video_doc_id=yt_SZrCWa38KHk&afv=True&plid=AAUGEJt8M_XIdPMy&ptk=erosentertainment&gut_tag=%2F4061%2Fytunknown%2Fmain&iv_module=http%3A%2F%2Fs.ytimg.com%2Fyts%2Fswfbin%2Fplayer-vflBE6Osg%2Fiv_module.swf&sffb=True&view_count=2116763&iurlmq=http%3A%2F%2Fi.ytimg.com%2Fvi%2FSZrCWa38KHk%2Fmqdefault.jpg&ad_slots=0&video_verticals=%5B360%2C+3%2C+1032%5D&probe_url=http%3A%2F%2Fr4---sn-4g57km7z.c.youtube.com%2Fvideogoodput%3Fid%3Do-AAWKlHqNPdO1X_UCiXV-zYfYLV7adMlrMc0MjAeE9qbX%26source%3Dgoodput%26range%3D0-99999%26expire%3D1414046881%26ip%3D115.118.224.92%26ms%3Dpm%26nh%3DEAM%26sparams%3Did%2Csource%2Crange%2Cexpire%2Cip%2Cms%2Cnh%26signature%3D6533DC27243135F989B5B46A63F78499E1B0358D.425BDF2C07A1ACF66064C589B46FF44B11AA1F10%26key%3Dcms1&ad_module=http%3A%2F%2Fs.ytimg.com%2Fyts%2Fswfbin%2Fplayer-vflBE6Osg%2Fad.swf&video_id=SZrCWa38KHk&midroll_prefetch_size=1&cbrver=33.0&has_cc=False&storyboard_spec=http%3A%2F%2Fi.ytimg.com%2Fsb%2FSZrCWa38KHk%2Fstoryboard3_L%24L%2F%24N.jpg%7C48%2327%23100%2310%2310%230%23default%23J6TCwwwIxDOsXPZYKBfCfigm0NU%7C80%2345%2343%2310%2310%231000%23M%24M%23P9rjlNIFYTQWSA2yFw5Ygb4N4UU%7C160%2390%2343%235%235%231000%23M%24M%23KJNqLK-I6HWaDoRBBGMqI7McM7o&allow_html5_ads=1&afv_ad_tag=http%3A%2F%2Fgoogleads.g.doubleclick.net%2Fpagead%2Fads%3Fad_type%3Dtext_image_flash%26channel%3Dyt_mpvid_nWND0Xo3pIKc8Zkn%252Byt_cid_133%252Byt_no_ap%252Bytdevice_1%252Bafv_user_id_nS5MV3PRAgTGu2Y2DdGhfQ%252Bafv_user_erostamil%252Bytel_embedded%252Bytps_default%252BVertical_3%252BVertical_34%252BVertical_35%252BVertical_360%252BVertical_593%252BVertical_1032%252Bafv_overlay%252Binvideo_overlay_480x70_cat10%26client%3Dca-pub-6219811747049371%26description_url%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.youtube.com%252Fvideo%252FSZrCWa38KHk%26hl%3Den%26host%3Dca-host-pub-2963038799018685%26ht_id%3D4184697%26loeid%3D910100%2C916942%2C924619%2C935000%2C935679%2C942484%2C945073%26url%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.youtube.com%252Fvideo%252FSZrCWa38KHk%26ytdevice%3D1%26yt_pt%3DAPb3F29Z68ojSDJwHCv6ckOLnO8PKY8a1IdOvpfZl1cKHu-epyRrJX1NjLGCp4GAtd6cvCaerZkcBEsTRMMZmWqxLPXcmk-LRXyM6rISqYZCwzOA29PWCFbevlzUYU_GT1CqjrrAF3hU7LTCfYUz5zrAjV9UA09M4vWgD84j1w&dashmpd=http%3A%2F%2Fmanifest.googlevideo.com%2Fapi%2Fmanifest%2Fdash%2Fsource%2Fyoutube%2Fsparams%2Fas%252Cid%252Cip%252Cipbits%252Citag%252Cmm%252Cms%252Cmv%252Cplayback_host%252Csource%252Cexpire%2Fmv%2Fm%2Fas%2Ffmp4_audio_clear%252Cwebm_audio_clear%252Cfmp4_sd_hd_clear%252Cwebm_sd_hd_clear%252Cwebm2_sd_hd_clear%2Fipbits%2F0%2Fms%2Fau%2Fmt%2F1414043211%2Fsver%2F3%2Fid%2Fo-AGo93ElNwiIuEXZTNdJN54VvKBf_28RexQxNuPDZKW-q%2Fexpire%2F1414064881%2Fsignature%2F041DA8753793BE9AD17E0363D8D7CCFFCB3682B5.899F37CBDD3EB9DE936F6BB6EDA0AC7BDF933419%2Fplayback_host%2Fr12---sn-cvh7zn7z.googlevideo.com%2Ffexp%2F910100%252C916942%252C924619%252C927622%252C930666%252C930672%252C931983%252C932404%252C935000%252C935679%252C942484%252C945073%252C947209%252C947225%252C948703%252C952302%2Fkey%2Fyt5%2Fip%2F115.118.224.92%2Fmm%2F31%2Fupn%2FDXKJ9e_BqsI%2Fitag%2F0&instream_long=False&tmi=1&cbr=Firefox&as_launched_in_country=1&url_encoded_fmt_stream_map=fallback_host%3Dtc.v21.cache6.googlevideo.com%26quality%3Dhd720%26type%3Dvideo%252Fmp4%253B%2Bcodecs%253D%2522avc1.64001F%252C%2Bmp4a.40.2%2522%26itag%3D22%26url%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fr12---sn-cvh7zn7z.googlevideo.com%252Fvideoplayback%253Fsource%253Dyoutube%2526sparams%253Did%25252Cinitcwndbps%25252Cip%25252Cipbits%25252Citag%25252Cmm%25252Cms%25252Cmv%25252Cratebypass%25252Csource%25252Cupn%25252Cexpire%2526mv%253Dm%2526initcwndbps%253D630000%2526ms%253Dau%2526sver%253D3%2526key%253Dyt5%2526signature%253D7AF7F006FC569EE15C04ADA1C9969DE304BDE5CE.6366A57082B284AB9642D6EB591903751A3BA2EA%2526mm%253D31%2526upn%253DBJKvd_nEpqw%2526itag%253D22%2526ipbits%253D0%2526mt%253D1414043211%2526id%253Do-AGo93ElNwiIuEXZTNdJN54VvKBf_28RexQxNuPDZKW-q%2526expire%253D1414064881%2526fexp%253D910100%25252C916942%25252C924619%25252C927622%25252C930666%25252C930672%25252C931983%25252C932404%25252C935000%25252C935679%25252C942484%25252C945073%25252C947209%25252C947225%25252C948703%25252C952302%2526ip%253D115.118.224.92%2526ratebypass%253Dyes%2Cfallback_host%3Dtc.v9.cache7.googlevideo.com%26quality%3Dmedium%26type%3Dvideo%252Fwebm%253B%2Bcodecs%253D%2522vp8.0%252C%2Bvorbis%2522%26itag%3D43%26url%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fr12---sn-cvh7zn7z.googlevideo.com%252Fvideoplayback%253Fsource%253Dyoutube%2526sparams%253Did%25252Cinitcwndbps%25252Cip%25252Cipbits%25252Citag%25252Cmm%25252Cms%25252Cmv%25252Cratebypass%25252Csource%25252Cupn%25252Cexpire%2526mv%253Dm%2526initcwndbps%253D630000%2526ms%253Dau%2526sver%253D3%2526key%253Dyt5%2526signature%253D13C4A61E9132AF216628CF5E4EEE0B2464803585.6F0297343C76EDFEDCA868D63C95A30EA47A92FF%2526mm%253D31%2526upn%253DBJKvd_nEpqw%2526itag%253D43%2526ipbits%253D0%2526mt%253D1414043211%2526id%253Do-AGo93ElNwiIuEXZTNdJN54VvKBf_28RexQxNuPDZKW-q%2526expire%253D1414064881%2526fexp%253D910100%25252C916942%25252C924619%25252C927622%25252C930666%25252C930672%25252C931983%25252C932404%25252C935000%25252C935679%25252C942484%25252C945073%25252C947209%25252C947225%25252C948703%25252C952302%2526ip%253D115.118.224.92%2526ratebypass%253Dyes%2Cfallback_host%3Dtc.v13.cache7.googlevideo.com%26quality%3Dmedium%26type%3Dvideo%252Fmp4%253B%2Bcodecs%253D%2522avc1.42001E%252C%2Bmp4a.40.2%2522%26itag%3D18%26url%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fr12---sn-cvh7zn7z.googlevideo.com%252Fvideoplayback%253Fsource%253Dyoutube%2526sparams%253Did%25252Cinitcwndbps%25252Cip%25252Cipbits%25252Citag%25252Cmm%25252Cms%25252Cmv%25252Cratebypass%25252Csource%25252Cupn%25252Cexpire%2526mv%253Dm%2526initcwndbps%253D630000%2526ms%253Dau%2526sver%253D3%2526key%253Dyt5%2526signature%253D845351087F936B5FEED7A6D887AB06095524925F.9F72CFC7B9555C047B57AFDAF8CA47864E40421C%2526mm%253D31%2526upn%253DBJKvd_nEpqw%2526itag%253D18%2526ipbits%253D0%2526mt%253D1414043211%2526id%253Do-AGo93ElNwiIuEXZTNdJN54VvKBf_28RexQxNuPDZKW-q%2526expire%253D1414064881%2526fexp%253D910100%25252C916942%25252C924619%25252C927622%25252C930666%25252C930672%25252C931983%25252C932404%25252C935000%25252C935679%25252C942484%25252C945073%25252C947209%25252C947225%25252C948703%25252C952302%2526ip%253D115.118.224.92%2526ratebypass%253Dyes%2Cfallback_host%3Dtc.v19.cache3.googlevideo.com%26quality%3Dsmall%26type%3Dvideo%252Fx-flv%26itag%3D5%26url%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fr12---sn-cvh7zn7z.googlevideo.com%252Fvideoplayback%253Fsource%253Dyoutube%2526sparams%253Did%25252Cinitcwndbps%25252Cip%25252Cipbits%25252Citag%25252Cmm%25252Cms%25252Cmv%25252Csource%25252Cupn%25252Cexpire%2526mv%253Dm%2526initcwndbps%253D630000%2526ms%253Dau%2526sver%253D3%2526key%253Dyt5%2526signature%253D54157417D91277FA4FE2FDF6A9B67D1A2E8C7F36.22E3E1A64A2F85435E15047B2C7330FBE9E23831%2526mm%253D31%2526upn%253DBJKvd_nEpqw%2526itag%253D5%2526ipbits%253D0%2526mt%253D1414043211%2526id%253Do-AGo93ElNwiIuEXZTNdJN54VvKBf_28RexQxNuPDZKW-q%2526expire%253D1414064881%2526fexp%253D910100%25252C916942%25252C924619%25252C927622%25252C930666%25252C930672%25252C931983%25252C932404%25252C935000%25252C935679%25252C942484%25252C945073%25252C947209%25252C947225%25252C948703%25252C952302%2526ip%253D115.118.224.92%2Cfallback_host%3Dtc.v24.cache6.googlevideo.com%26quality%3Dsmall%26type%3Dvideo%252F3gpp%253B%2Bcodecs%253D%2522mp4v.20.3%252C%2Bmp4a.40.2%2522%26itag%3D36%26url%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fr12---sn-cvh7zn7z.googlevideo.com%252Fvideoplayback%253Fsource%253Dyoutube%2526sparams%253Did%25252Cinitcwndbps%25252Cip%25252Cipbits%25252Citag%25252Cmm%25252Cms%25252Cmv%25252Csource%25252Cupn%25252Cexpire%2526mv%253Dm%2526initcwndbps%253D630000%2526ms%253Dau%2526sver%253D3%2526key%253Dyt5%2526signature%253DDE5DC5F4408DEB07A53070ABA173C2B1ED652777.F54F17048E265671845D9CC2FF1F4966470BDB9E%2526mm%253D31%2526upn%253DBJKvd_nEpqw%2526itag%253D36%2526ipbits%253D0%2526mt%253D1414043211%2526id%253Do-AGo93ElNwiIuEXZTNdJN54VvKBf_28RexQxNuPDZKW-q%2526expire%253D1414064881%2526fexp%253D910100%25252C916942%25252C924619%25252C927622%25252C930666%25252C930672%25252C931983%25252C932404%25252C935000%25252C935679%25252C942484%25252C945073%25252C947209%25252C947225%25252C948703%25252C952302%2526ip%253D115.118.224.92%2Cfallback_host%3Dtc.v14.cache7.googlevideo.com%26quality%3Dsmall%26type%3Dvideo%252F3gpp%253B%2Bcodecs%253D%2522mp4v.20.3%252C%2Bmp4a.40.2%2522%26itag%3D17%26url%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fr12---sn-cvh7zn7z.googlevideo.com%252Fvideoplayback%253Fsource%253Dyoutube%2526sparams%253Did%25252Cinitcwndbps%25252Cip%25252Cipbits%25252Citag%25252Cmm%25252Cms%25252Cmv%25252Csource%25252Cupn%25252Cexpire%2526mv%253Dm%2526initcwndbps%253D630000%2526ms%253Dau%2526sver%253D3%2526key%253Dyt5%2526signature%253DCA361E5EE2F02C920C9269588F2FB0FC5969B701.1BA602BDE8ABCD0BB047026CAE41EC09F2DF3548%2526mm%253D31%2526upn%253DBJKvd_nEpqw%2526itag%253D17%2526ipbits%253D0%2526mt%253D1414043211%2526id%253Do-AGo93ElNwiIuEXZTNdJN54VvKBf_28RexQxNuPDZKW-q%2526expire%253D1414064881%2526fexp%253D910100%25252C916942%25252C924619%25252C927622%25252C930666%25252C930672%25252C931983%25252C932404%25252C935000%25252C935679%25252C942484%25252C945073%25252C947209%25252C947225%25252C948703%25252C952302%2526ip%253D115.118.224.92&iv3_module=1&iurlsd=http%3A%2F%2Fi.ytimg.com%2Fvi%2FSZrCWa38KHk%2Fsddefault.jpg&mpvid=nWND0Xo3pIKc8Zkn&ad_device=1&author=Eros+Tamil&tag_for_child_directed=False&cafe_experiment_id=&fexp=910100%2C916942%2C924619%2C927622%2C930666%2C930672%2C931983%2C932404%2C935000%2C935679%2C942484%2C945073%2C947209%2C947225%2C948703%2C952302&iurl=http%3A%2F%2Fi.ytimg.com%2Fvi%2FSZrCWa38KHk%2Fhqdefault.jpg&keywords=Selfie+pulla%2Cselfie+pulla+song%2Cselfie+pulla+full+song%2Cselfie+pulla+song+kaththi%2Cselfie+pulla+kaththi%2Ckaththi+songs%2Ckaththi+movie+songs%2Ckaththi+2014+songs%2CVijay%2CSamantha%2CSathish%2CNeil+Nitin+Mukesh%2CAnirudh%2CIlayathalapathy+Vijay%2CSunidhi+Chauhan%2Cerosnow%2Ckathi%2Ckaththi%2Ckaththi+trailer%2Ckaththi+movie%2Ckaththi+music%2Ckathi+songs&vq=auto&token=vjVQa1PpcFN2zI6Fk2Ai7peVUIYObByCKA__BYZoovU%3D&account_playback_token=QUFFLUhqbV93Wmkyd3Bic3FtMlRnNE82RDJIV0VVNzYwZ3xBQ3Jtc0tuWGRXZHFUbE0ta2NxbW9VOHBVeVhxTzJzNnNLSkZ0X2NzQ0FPXzFBSDhIRVJWMEVTakRMTk9PTW1xNkFiSk8tZVZtVDREVmFLbzhaQkFQZ2xCN2lSYm9NeWlfZnVTaDBUNGhkenFfMGQydVNVUkZZSQ%3D%3D&allowed_ads=set%28%5B0%2C+1%2C+2%2C+4%2C+8%2C+9%2C+10%5D%29&fmt_list=22%2F1280x720%2F9%2F0%2F115%2C43%2F640x360%2F99%2F0%2F0%2C18%2F640x360%2F9%2F0%2F115%2C5%2F426x240%2F7%2F0%2F0%2C36%2F426x240%2F99%2F1%2F0%2C17%2F256x144%2F99%2F1%2F0&show_content_thumbnail=True&ptchn=nS5MV3PRAgTGu2Y2DdGhfQ&excluded_ads=3%3D1_1%2C1_2%2C1_2_1%2C1_3%2C2_2%2C2_2_1%2C2_3&iv_allow_in_place_switch=1&thumbnail_url=http%3A%2F%2Fi.ytimg.com%2Fvi%2FSZrCWa38KHk%2Fdefault.jpg&length_seconds=42&iurlhq=http%3A%2F%2Fi.ytimg.com%2Fvi%2FSZrCWa38KHk%2Fhqdefault.jpg&loeid=910100%2C916942%2C924619%2C935000%2C935679%2C942484%2C945073&cid=133&pyv_in_related_cafe_experiment_id=&cl=78195662&oid=4o6aB3j8mrrK7wW3MpJwkw&hl=en_US&dash=1

Decoded response using this code

`string videoInfo = System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlDecode(strResponse);`

Now i want to split decoded response like this coded in java

```
String[] formats = strResponse.get("url_encoded_fmt_stream_map").split(",");
```

How to code this in c#

Comment: what does `GetURL` do?

Comment: The GetURL method fetches a url-resource as a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var coll = System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(queryString);
string url = coll["url"];
string type = coll["type"];
```

Comment: System.Web.HttpUtility does not contain a definition for 'QueryParseString' 
Getting this error

Comment: @Virender: Oops, a type. It's [ParseQueryString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms150046%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: can i use split function like this
string url = col["url"].Split(',');

Thanks for your quick reply!

Comment: @Virender: You can use [Uri class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z6c2z492%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to parse url itself. Then use HttpUtility.ParseQueryString() to parse query string. If one of the elements as url again, you can use Uri again.